# How to get number of list element (ul tag) of HTML using Get matching XPath count?

Tags: xpath, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm kind of new to XPATH-query. I use RF and selenium2library and the XPath Helper-plugin in chrome to test a certain website page. I'm new to HTML/CSS/JavaScript as well.

The web page consists of two ULs (lists) for left and right sides of the page and each one has a few LIs which have few divisions comprised of widgets (JPEG images etc).

I need to **count this list rows** (number of LIs in each UL). I have already done the samething  in a drop down menu to count its elements with no problem (perhaps because it was considered 
a web element). But right now I use the same "Get Matching Xpath Count" which returns almost the whole page HTML source instead of a number and it then fails.

All my program is based on getting the number of LIs in a UL (of drop down menu, page, table,...). so I wonder what to do now. Here is an example of the HTML code of the page:

```
<ul class="rqcol" id="col8a580456553ae">
 <li class="rqportlet"  id="por8a58045655">
   <div id="hdrpor8a580" class="rqhdr" onmouseover="RQ.util.showTools(this)" onmouseout="RQ.util.hideTools(this)"> </div> </li>
 <li class="rqportlet" id="por8a580456" >
   <div id="hdrpor8a581" class="rqhdr" onmouseover="RQ.util.showTools(this)" onmouseout="RQ.util.hideTools(this)"> </div></li>
</ul>
```

and my code was:

```
Get Matching Xpath Count  |  //ul[@id="ccol8a580456553ae"]/li
```

which does give me some texts plus HTML code.i also tried:

```
Get Length |  //ul[@id="ccol8a580456553ae"]
```

which doesn't give me 2 but a big number.

Answer (score 0):

An XPath 2.0 expression to count the 'li' for the specific '' would be:

```
//ul[@id="col8a580456553ae"]/count(li)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this new chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/relative-xpath-helper/eanaofphbanknlngejejepmfomkjaiic

Answer (score 0):

You've  made a typo in the `id` value - an extra "c" char in the beginning; otherwise the xpath is correct:

```
${count}=    Get Matching Xpath Count    //ul[@id="col8a580456553ae"]/li
```

By the way, the keyword `Get Matching Xpath Count` is deprecated in the latest version of the SeleniumLibrary, in favour of `Get Element Count`